# React Native: Display array of pixels in Image component (blurhash)

Tags: arrays, node.js, reactjs, image, react-native

How would I display an array of pixels (`UInt8ClampedArray` or `UInt8Array`) in a React Native `<Image>` component?

I'm using the [blurhash](https://github.com/woltapp/blurhash/tree/master/TypeScript) library to decode a string my web-endpoint has sent me, let's say `UAKBgy~qM|IU0000-;M{_3t5D%RQ00_3xaIU`, which I want to render as a blurred Image in my View.

I've tried setting it to the `uri` property of the Image source, but the image just didn't display anything.

```js
import { decode } from 'blurhash';
// ...
const myHash = 'UAKBgy~qM|IU0000-;M{_3t5D%RQ00_3xaIU';
const result = decode(myHash, 32, 32);
const base64 = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${result.toString()}`;
const imgSource = { uri: base64 };
// ...
<Image source={imgSource} ...
```

The `decode` function returns an `UInt8ClampedArray`, which cannot be used as an Image source.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Looks like the decode function gives back raw image data. You can possibly use a js based png/jpeg encoder and encode the raw image to the right format before constructing a data uri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've spent a long time trying to figure this out. I've ended up creating my own native UI module which decodes the image natively, and renders it using native Image components (`UIImageView` on iOS and `ReactImageView` on Android).

Check it out at: [mrousavy/react-native-blurhash](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-blurhash)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [React-Native-Skia](https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia) can do that. Here's an example from the documentation:

```
import { Skia, AlphaType, ColorType } from "@shopify/react-native-skia";
 
const pixels = new Uint8Array(256 * 256 * 4);
pixels.fill(255);
let i = 0;
for (let x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
    pixels[i++] = (x * y) % 255;
  }
}
const data = Skia.Data.fromBytes(pixels);
const img = Skia.Image.MakeImage(
  {
    width: 256,
    height: 256,
    alphaType: AlphaType.Opaque,
    colorType: ColorType.RGBA_8888,
  },
  data,
  256 * 4
);
```

See https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/images#makeimage